# Is there a way to download Twilio call recordings with a file name that makes sense?

Tags: download, twilio, twilio-api, long-filenames, call-recording

From Twilio I was able to download call recording files.  I was also successful in downloading CallSID CSV file.  The call recording filename does not give any hint about the phone numbers involved, etc.        I can't find a way to simply match them up or simply rename the audio file to something understandable like.....  DATE-FROM-18135551212-TO-13334445555.mp3 
If I could do this, I could simply download the files from Twilio to my hard drive and search for a call later by date or phone number. I've got calls online going back to 2017 so the storage on Twilio is pretty high right now.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot control the recording file names. You can use the filename which is the recordingSID and then use the following below, to get the details behind the recording.

1. Fetch the recording metadata which includes the CallSID (by using the recordingSID).

[Fetch Recording Metadata](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/recording#fetch-recording-metadata)

2. Fetch details on the CallSID

[Fetch a Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call?code-sample=code-fetch-a-call)